My DevOps Pipeline Architecture has 42 build pipelines - am I doing it wrong?
Hello fellow DevOps Architects!
What exactly am I even asking?
I've come up with a proposed approach which includes 42 Build Pipelines and a further 6 release pipelines. Maybe this is just how "big software" works - and it's totally fine and exactly how this is supposed to work? ‍♂️
But equally - maybe I'm missing a trick, and there is a much better way of doing this? I'd basically like a bit of a sanity check on this.
Intro
I am considering a re-design of our build and release pipelines for a fairly large and complex solution - all of which is hosted on Microsoft Azure. This consists of:

A single Shared App Service
3x Web Apps
2x Function Apps
Multiple overlapping config components (AppConfig / KeyVault, EventGrid, Redis Cache, AI Search, Storage Accounts and CosmosDBs .. etc etc)
An "Infrastructure" project which provisions all of the cloud services
(we are using Pulumi, but for this example could just as easily be
ARM or Bicep based).

The problem space
One of the issues we have faced is major features overlapping during development.
We need to be able to push these into separate environments for testing BEFORE we merge them into our main RELEASE branch - otherwise we end up with a big monolithic code base which includes both "ready to release" as well as "buggy / awaiting testing" code at the same time.
To complicate this - the solution contains multiple overlapping disciplines; React, C#, Python, Machine Learning .. and with a lot of moving parts (e.g. Cognitive Services and Azure Search services) so it's unlikely that people can dev and test locally on just their own box. We need to bring stuff together in order to be able to integration test stuff.
We basically need to have multiple full end-to-end "build > deploy > test" lifecycles available so that code merges don't end up getting muddled - and allowing our acceptance testing to independently test features for release.
We ALSO want to be able to release each component with a fair degree of independence - so we can push out a single web app without releasing code to everything else.
Proposed Architecture
So I've suggested an initial approach with 6 different code branches for EACH Repo that we use:
each of these would have a corresponding hosted cloud environment we can deploy to

RELEASE (for the main production release process into formal TEST / STAGE / LIVE)
PATCH (for patching emergent bugs on live code)
RC1 (Release Candidate Branch)
RC2 (Release Candidate Branch)
RC3 (Release Candidate Branch)
DEV1 (Dev Branch)
DEV2 (Dev Branch)
DEV3 (Dev Branch)

The idea for the RC and DEV branches is that it allows us to collaboratively develop multiple major features simultaneously, but independently (in the DEV1, DEV2, DEV3 branches) - and these can then be released to testers (in the RC1, RC2, and RC3 environments).
Why do we need specifically named branches?
.. why don't we just create feature branches on the fly?
Well - this is driven partly from both Auth0 and Pulumi. Both of which require specific named environments (on the Auth0 side we need to define the callback URLs for 0Auth to work correctly), so we need these to be defined in advance.
It also makes testing a lot easier because we have Custom Domains setup for everything.
So what exactly feels wrong about this?
For me .. it's the scale.
We currently have six different build artifacts (3x Web Apps, 2x Function Apps, 1x Infrastructure). This is likely to grow going forward.
We also have 8 branches, and again this might grow going forward.
So that is 42 separate build pipelines (6x artifacts, in 8x branches) - and a further 6x release pipelines (one for each branch - triggered by the artifact drops).
Is that .. too many? Is that how many you are supposed to have? Are there some people out there going "LMAO .. we have hundreds! this is small fry!" or am I missing something?
Should I be looking at a more clever way of branching, building, and merging the code?
...
I guess what I'm really looking for is a nod and sanity check that I'm not doing anything crazy!
If you've managed to reach the end of this post then I very much thank you for your time - and would appreciate your thoughts!

There is no right or wrong assessment of the number of pipelines. The number of pipelines should be based on the actual needs of all projects. I have checked your description, you have multiple repo solutions in different languages and have multiple branches during development process.  In this case, it is acceptable to have 42 separate pipelines to handle building and deploying different repos and resources.

If you want to optimize the number of Pipelines, you can check if there are branches/repos that can share the same Pipeline definition. If so, you can add features like repo resources in Pipeline to share Pipeline definitions.

I agree with Kevin's suggestions.
I am considering a re-design of our build and release pipelines - if you're using classical pipelines, the best advice I can give you is to start using YAML pipelines when you can - there is a learning curve but it is worth in the mid-long term. See Scaling CI/CD Pipelines with Azure DevOps- YAML Based Approach

Ok thank you - I appreciate the comments - and yes to Rui, we are already using YAML based build pipelines. But keep the Build/Release pipelines separate

@MartinHatch You can continue to build and deploy according to your current configuration. If you want to optimize Pipelines, you can share more details about Pipelines in the future. We will provide you with suggestions.

I'm assuming you are using Git for Source Control. I would avoid having a pipeline per branch. That could become a maintenance nightmare over time, even if you use a lot of templating. I would have a single pipeline per "thing" and then use expressions / conditions if I needed to change the flow of the pipeline due to which branch it was running from.
Here is an example pipeline that will always build the code and then will use conditions and expressions to decide which environment is deployed to.

Dev environment is only deployed to when running from a Dev Branch.
Test environment is always deployed to
Prod environment is only deployed to from the Release or Patch branches



trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')] # is the pipeline running against the Main branch
  isRelease: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release')] # is the pipeling runnins against the Release branch
  isPatch: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/patch')] # is the pipeline running against the Patch branch
  isDev: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev')] # is the pipeline running against any branch that starts with Dev
  isRC: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/RC')] # is the pipeline running against any branch that starts with RC
  isPullRequest: $[eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')] # is the pipeline running as part of a Pull Request

stages:
  - stage: build
    jobs:
      - job: build
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                Write-Host "Build some code"
                write-Host "isMain" $(isMain)
                write-Host "isRelease" $(isRelease)
                write-Host "isPatch" $(isPatch)
                write-Host "isDev" $(isDev)
                write-Host "isRC" $(isRC)
                write-Host "isPullRequest" $(isPullRequest)

          - task: PowerShell@2
            # Only run this task if the branch is release or the reason is PR
            condition: or(eq(variables.isRelease, 'true'), eq(variables.isPullRequest, 'true'))
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                Write-Host "Run SonarQube"

  # only generate the stage if we're running from a dev branch (note the indentation)
  # we cannot use the "isDev" variable as the variable is only available at runtime and the 
  # expression needs the value at compile time
  - ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev') }}:
    - stage: deploy_to_dev
      jobs:
        - deployment: build
          environment: dev
          strategy:
            runOnce:
              deploy:
                steps:
                  - task: PowerShell@2
                    inputs:
                      targetType: 'inline'
                      script: |
                        Write-Host "Deploy some code"

  - stage: deploy_to_test
    jobs:
      - deployment: build
        environment: test
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: PowerShell@2
                  inputs:
                    targetType: 'inline'
                    script: |
                      Write-Host "Deploy some code"

  - stage: deploy_to_prod
    # only run this stage if the branch is Release or Patch
    # unlike the deploy_to_dev stage, this stage will be generated for all runs, but will be skipped if the
    # pipeline is not running on the Release or Patch branch
    condition: or(eq(variables.isRelease, 'true'), eq(variables.isPatch, 'true'))
    jobs:
      - deployment: build
        environment: prod
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: PowerShell@2
                  inputs:
                    targetType: 'inline'
                    script: |
                      Write-Host "Deploy some code"



